# How do I send user inputs (HTML) to an array in Angular?

Tags: html, angularjs

How do I get the inputs from this form to go into an array in angular?

```
<form>
        <tr>
          <td class="Meal-form">
            <input type="date" ng-model="date" placeholder="select" required></td>
          <td>
            <select ng-model="meal" ng-options="meals.name for meals in mealTypes">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="about" placeholder="What did you eat" required></td>
          <td>
            <select ng-model= "feel" ng-options="feeling.name for feeling in feels">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Content"></td>
        </tr>
</form>
```

I get how to pull the information from angular to HTML, but not how to get the HTML to angular.

Comment: What do you expect the array to look like?

Comment: `$scope.journals = [
 {
  date: '',
  meal: '',
  food: '',
  reaction: ''
 }]`

Comment: make an ng-click function that when submit is clicked it creates an array and pushes $scope.date , $scope.meal, $scope.about, $scope.feel into it.

Comment: Anything that within html is in ng-model, is accessible in your controller via `$scope.about` and if for example on click of submit you want the data to be pushed into array, than just create something like `$scope.addToList = function() {data = {id: 1, name : $scope.about, test: $scope.fell}; $scope.myList.push(data)}`, bind this to your button via ng-click and this should work

Comment: Why do you want that to be an array which simply wraps one object?  In any case, you can just create the object like `$scope.journals = [{date: $scope.date}]`, or whatever

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your model in controller, and save function

```
$scope.model = {
  date: '',
  meal: '',
  about:'',
  feel: ''
};

$scope.save = function()
{
   alert($scope.model.date);
   alert($scope.model.meal);

   $scope.yourarray.push($scope.model);
}
```

You Html need to change

```
<form>
        <tr>
          <td class="Meal-form">
            <input type="date" ng-model="model.date" placeholder="select" required></td>
          <td>
            <select ng-model="model.meal" ng-options="meals.name for meals in mealTypes">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="text" ng-model="model.about" placeholder="What did you eat" required></td>
          <td>
            <select ng-model= "model.feel" ng-options="feeling.name for feeling in feels">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="buttton" ng-click="save()" id="submit" value="Submit Content"></td>
        </tr>
</form>
```

Note the ng-bind, it should be like this `ng-model="model.date"`

Comment: don't need to declare all the properties in controller, `ng-model` will create them for you , simpler to just do `$scope.model={}`

Comment: So is this taking the inputs from the user and storing them in $scope.save or in $scope.model? The next thing I want to do is create another row on the table with the information that user has input using ng-repeat. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng-model` you create a dual-binding relationship between your view (the HTML) and your model (the JS). That is to say when the user types in to your form, you can then do

```
console.log($scope.date)
```

to print the date they entered.